# Why isn't the sort_by_name parameter working on ActiveCollab API?

Tags: php, api, activecollab

I'm calling ActiveCollab API with:

```
$query = $client->get('projects', ['sort_by_name' => true]);
```

But the `sort_by_name` is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using ActiveCollab PHP client:

https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk

If you check the signature of the `get` method, you'll notice that it accepts a **single** argument, so your call should be like this:

```
$query = $client->get('projects?sort_by_name=1');
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I am using that client.  I recommend adding this info to your API docs.  Thanks!